# Why is my output not as expected? (Simple OpAmp Circuit)

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a very simple OpAmp circuit using an LM324.  I used that because it is apparently the equiv of the NTE987 that I actually got from Microcenter.  I was just playing around with the old school Forest Mimms Enegeers Mini Notebook series (OP Amp IC Circuits).  I was trying to do circuit 1 (yes, thats right, I am having issues with the first circuit. :\ ).

## Setup

I am trying to simulate the circuit using `ngspice` through KiCad.  The schematic that I generated is the following:

[image]

I used the following `pspice` model from http://www.ti.com/product/LM324/toolssoftware

```
* LMX24_LM2902 - Rev. A
* Created by Paul Goedeke; November 16, 2018
* Created with Green-Williams-Lis Op Amp Macro-model Architecture
* Copyright 2018 by Texas Instruments Corporation
******************************************************
* MACRO-MODEL SIMULATED PARAMETERS:
******************************************************
* OPEN-LOOP GAIN AND PHASE VS. FREQUENCY  WITH RL, CL EFFECTS (Aol)
* UNITY GAIN BANDWIDTH (GBW)
* INPUT COMMON-MODE REJECTION RATIO VS. FREQUENCY (CMRR)
* POWER SUPPLY REJECTION RATIO VS. FREQUENCY (PSRR)
* DIFFERENTIAL INPUT IMPEDANCE (Zid)
* COMMON-MODE INPUT IMPEDANCE (Zic)
* OPEN-LOOP OUTPUT IMPEDANCE VS. FREQUENCY (Zo)
* OUTPUT CURRENT THROUGH THE SUPPLY (Iout)
* INPUT VOLTAGE NOISE DENSITY VS. FREQUENCY (en)
* INPUT CURRENT NOISE DENSITY VS. FREQUENCY (in)
* OUTPUT VOLTAGE SWING vs. OUTPUT CURRENT (Vo)
* SHORT-CIRCUIT OUTPUT CURRENT (Isc)
* QUIESCENT CURRENT (Iq)
* SETTLING TIME VS. CAPACITIVE LOAD (ts)
* SLEW RATE (SR)
* SMALL SIGNAL OVERSHOOT VS. CAPACITIVE LOAD
* LARGE SIGNAL RESPONSE
* OVERLOAD RECOVERY TIME (tor)
* INPUT BIAS CURRENT (Ib)
* INPUT OFFSET CURRENT (Ios)
* INPUT OFFSET VOLTAGE (Vos)
* INPUT COMMON-MODE VOLTAGE RANGE (Vcm)
* INPUT OFFSET VOLTAGE VS. INPUT COMMON-MODE VOLTAGE (Vos vs. Vcm)
* INPUT/OUTPUT ESD CELLS (ESDin, ESDout)
******************************************************
.subckt LMX24_LM2902 IN+ IN- VCC VEE OUT
******************************************************
* MODEL DEFINITIONS:
.model BB_SW VSWITCH(Ron=50 Roff=1e12 Von=700e-3 Voff=0)
.model ESD_SW VSWITCH(Ron=50 Roff=1e12 Von=250e-3 Voff=0)
.model OL_SW VSWITCH(Ron=1e-3 Roff=1e9 Von=900e-3 Voff=800e-3)
.model OR_SW VSWITCH(Ron=10e-3 Roff=1e9 Von=1e-3 Voff=0)
.model R_NOISELESS RES(T_ABS=-273.15)
******************************************************


I_OS        ESDn MID -18N
I_B         37 MID -20N
V_GRp       57 MID 180
V_GRn       58 MID -180
V_ISCp      51 MID 40
V_ISCn      52 MID -40
V_ORn       45 VCLP -1.2
V11         56 44 0
V_ORp       43 VCLP 1.2
V12         55 42 0
V4          33 OUT 0
VCM_MIN     79 VEE_B 0
VCM_MAX     80 VCC_B -1.5
I_Q         VCC VEE 175U
V_OS        86 37 1.8M
R61         MID 22 R_NOISELESS 8.001K 
C16         22 23 19.89P 
R58         23 22 R_NOISELESS 100MEG 
GVCCS2      23 MID VEE_B MID  -992.9M
R57         MID 23 R_NOISELESS 1 
XU3         VCC_B VEE_B 24 25 26 27 MID PHASEREV_0
XU1         VIMON MID CRS CRS_DIST_0
C21         28 29 313.8N  
C22         30 31 636.6F  
R70         31 MID R_NOISELESS 2.5 
R67         31 30 R_NOISELESS 10K 
R66         30 MID R_NOISELESS 1 
XU2         31 MID MID 32 VCCS_LIM_ZO_0
GVCCS4      30 MID 29 MID  -4.3
R65         29 MID R_NOISELESS 3.03K 
R64         29 28 R_NOISELESS 10K 
R63         28 MID R_NOISELESS 1 
GVCCS3      28 MID CL_CLAMP 33  -90
R62         32 MID R_NOISELESS 1 
C29         34 MID 47F 
R78         MID 34 R_NOISELESS 1MEG 
GVCCS9      34 MID 35 MID  -1U
XU5         36 MID MID CLAMP CRS MID VCCS_LIM_2_EN_0
C28         38 MID 1P 
R77         39 38 R_NOISELESS 100 
C27         40 MID 1P 
R76         41 40 R_NOISELESS 100 
R75         MID 42 R_NOISELESS 1 
GVCCS8      42 MID 43 MID  -1
R74         44 MID R_NOISELESS 1 
GVCCS7      44 MID 45 MID  -1
Xi_nn       ESDn MID FEMT_0
Xi_np       MID 37 FEMT_0
Xe_n        ESDp 37 VNSE_0
C25         35 MID 47F 
R69         MID 35 R_NOISELESS 1MEG 
GVCCS6      35 MID VSENSE MID  -1U
C20         CLAMP MID 9N 
R68         MID CLAMP R_NOISELESS 1MEG 
R44         MID 36 R_NOISELESS 1MEG 
XVCCS_LIM_1 46 27 MID 36 VCCS_LIM_1_0
Rdummy      MID 33 R_NOISELESS 25K 
Rx          33 32 R_NOISELESS 250K 
R56         MID 47 R_NOISELESS 1K 
C15         47 48 1.592P 
R55         48 47 R_NOISELESS 100MEG 
GVCCS1      48 MID VCC_B MID  -100M
R54         MID 48 R_NOISELESS 1 
R49         MID 49 R_NOISELESS 4.616K 
C14         49 50 26.53P 
R48         50 49 R_NOISELESS 100MEG 
G_adjust    50 MID ESDp MID  -685.2M
Rsrc        MID 50 R_NOISELESS 1 
XIQPos      VIMON MID MID VCC VCCS_LIMIT_IQ_0
XIQNeg      MID VIMON VEE MID VCCS_LIMIT_IQ_0
C_DIFF      ESDp ESDn 1P 
XCL_AMP     51 52 VIMON MID 53 54 CLAMP_AMP_LO_0
SOR_SWp     CLAMP 55 CLAMP 55  S_VSWITCH_1
SOR_SWn     56 CLAMP 56 CLAMP  S_VSWITCH_2
XGR_AMP     57 58 59 MID 60 61 CLAMP_AMP_HI_0
R39         57 MID R_NOISELESS 1T 
R37         58 MID R_NOISELESS 1T 
R42         VSENSE 59 R_NOISELESS 1M 
C19         59 MID 1F 
R38         60 MID R_NOISELESS 1 
R36         MID 61 R_NOISELESS 1 
R40         60 62 R_NOISELESS 1M 
R41         61 63 R_NOISELESS 1M 
C17         62 MID 1F 
C18         MID 63 1F 
XGR_SRC     62 63 CLAMP MID VCCS_LIM_GR_0
R21         53 MID R_NOISELESS 1 
R20         MID 54 R_NOISELESS 1 
R29         53 64 R_NOISELESS 1M 
R30         54 65 R_NOISELESS 1M 
C9          64 MID 1F 
C8          MID 65 1F 
XCL_SRC     64 65 CL_CLAMP MID VCCS_LIM_4_0
R22         51 MID R_NOISELESS 1T 
R19         MID 52 R_NOISELESS 1T 
XCLAWp      VIMON MID 66 VCC_B VCCS_LIM_CLAW+_0
XCLAWn      MID VIMON VEE_B 67 VCCS_LIM_CLAW-_0
R12         66 VCC_B R_NOISELESS 1K 
R16         66 68 R_NOISELESS 1M 
R13         VEE_B 67 R_NOISELESS 1K 
R17         69 67 R_NOISELESS 1M 
C6          69 MID 1F 
C5          MID 68 1F 
G2          VCC_CLP MID 68 MID  -1M
R15         VCC_CLP MID R_NOISELESS 1K 
G3          VEE_CLP MID 69 MID  -1M
R14         MID VEE_CLP R_NOISELESS 1K 
XCLAW_AMP   VCC_CLP VEE_CLP VOUT_S MID 70 71 CLAMP_AMP_LO_0
R26         VCC_CLP MID R_NOISELESS 1T 
R23         VEE_CLP MID R_NOISELESS 1T 
R25         70 MID R_NOISELESS 1 
R24         MID 71 R_NOISELESS 1 
R27         70 72 R_NOISELESS 1M 
R28         71 73 R_NOISELESS 1M 
C11         72 MID 1F 
C10         MID 73 1F 
XCLAW_SRC   72 73 CLAW_CLAMP MID VCCS_LIM_3_0
H2          41 MID V11 -1
H3          39 MID V12 1
C12         SW_OL MID 100P 
R32         74 SW_OL R_NOISELESS 100 
R31         74 MID R_NOISELESS 1 
XOL_SENSE   MID 74 40 38 OL_SENSE_0
S1          28 29 SW_OL MID  S_VSWITCH_3
H1          75 MID V4 1K
S7          VEE OUT VEE OUT  S_VSWITCH_4
S6          OUT VCC OUT VCC  S_VSWITCH_5
R11         MID 76 R_NOISELESS 1T 
R18         76 VOUT_S R_NOISELESS 100 
C7          VOUT_S MID 10P 
E5          76 MID OUT MID  1
C13         VIMON MID 10P 
R33         75 VIMON R_NOISELESS 100 
R10         MID 75 R_NOISELESS 1T 
R47         77 VCLP R_NOISELESS 100 
C24         VCLP MID 100P 
E4          77 MID CL_CLAMP MID  1
R46         MID CL_CLAMP R_NOISELESS 1K 
G9          CL_CLAMP MID CLAW_CLAMP MID  -1M
R45         MID CLAW_CLAMP R_NOISELESS 1K 
G8          CLAW_CLAMP MID 34 MID  -1M
R43         MID VSENSE R_NOISELESS 1K 
G15         VSENSE MID CLAMP MID  -1M
C4          46 MID 1F 
R9          46 78 R_NOISELESS 1M 
R7          MID 79 R_NOISELESS 1T 
R6          80 MID R_NOISELESS 1T 
R8          MID 78 R_NOISELESS 1 
XVCM_CLAMP  26 MID 78 MID 80 79 VCCS_EXT_LIM_0
E1          MID 0 81 0  1
R89         VEE_B 0 R_NOISELESS 1 
R5          82 VEE_B R_NOISELESS 1M 
C3          82 0 1F 
R60         81 82 R_NOISELESS 1MEG 
C1          81 0 1 
R3          81 0 R_NOISELESS 1T 
R59         83 81 R_NOISELESS 1MEG 
C2          83 0 1F 
R4          VCC_B 83 R_NOISELESS 1M 
R88         VCC_B 0 R_NOISELESS 1 
G17         VEE_B 0 VEE 0  -1
G16         VCC_B 0 VCC 0  -1
R_PSR       84 24 R_NOISELESS 1K 
G_PSR       24 84 47 22  -1M
R2          25 ESDn R_NOISELESS 1M 
R1          84 85 R_NOISELESS 1M 
R_CMR       86 85 R_NOISELESS 1K 
G_CMR       85 86 49 MID  -1M
C_CMn       ESDn MID 2P 
C_CMp       MID ESDp 2P 
R53         ESDn MID R_NOISELESS 1T 
R52         MID ESDp R_NOISELESS 1T 
R35         IN- ESDn R_NOISELESS 10M 
R34         IN+ ESDp R_NOISELESS 10M 

.MODEL S_VSWITCH_1 VSWITCH (RON=10M ROFF=1T VON=10M VOFF=0)
.MODEL S_VSWITCH_2 VSWITCH (RON=10M ROFF=1T VON=10M VOFF=0)
.MODEL S_VSWITCH_3 VSWITCH (RON=1M ROFF=1T VON=500M VOFF=100M)
.MODEL S_VSWITCH_4 VSWITCH (RON=50 ROFF=1T VON=500M VOFF=450M)
.MODEL S_VSWITCH_5 VSWITCH (RON=50 ROFF=1T VON=500M VOFF=450M)

.ENDS LMX24_LM2902
*
.SUBCKT PHASEREV_0  VCC VEE VIN+ VIN- VOUT+ VOUT- MID
E1 VOUT+ MID VALUE={IF(V(VIN+,MID)<V(VEE,MID)-0.3,V(VCC,MID),V(VIN+,MID))}
E2 VOUT- MID VALUE={IF(V(VIN-,MID)<V(VEE,MID)-0.3,V(VCC,MID),V(VIN-,MID))}
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT CRS_DIST_0  VIMON MID OUT
V1 VREF MID -40M
ESHF VSHF MID VIMON VREF 1
GZC MID ZC VALUE = {SGN(V(VSHF,MID))}
R1 ZC MID 1
C1 ZC MID 2U
GCR MID OUT VALUE = {IF((ABS(V(ZC,MID))<=0.9),0,1)}
R2 OUT MID 1
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT VCCS_LIM_ZO_0  VC+ VC- IOUT+ IOUT-
.PARAM GAIN = 4E3
.PARAM IPOS = 1E6
.PARAM INEG = -1E6
G1 IOUT+ IOUT- VALUE={LIMIT(GAIN*V(VC+,VC-),INEG,IPOS)}
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT VCCS_LIM_2_EN_0  VC+ VC- IOUT+ IOUT- EN MID
.PARAM GAIN = 8.4E-4
.PARAM IPOS = 0.0048
.PARAM INEG = -0.0048
G1 IOUT+ IOUT- VALUE={LIMIT(GAIN*V(EN,MID)*V(VC+,VC-),INEG,IPOS)}
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT FEMT_0  1 2
.PARAM FLWF=1E-3
.PARAM NLFF=500
.PARAM NVRF=500
.PARAM GLFF={PWR(FLWF,0.25)*NLFF/1164}
.PARAM RNVF={1.184*PWR(NVRF,2)}
.MODEL DVNF D KF={PWR(FLWF,0.5)/1E11} IS=1.0E-16
I1 0 7 10E-3
I2 0 8 10E-3
D1 7 0 DVNF
D2 8 0 DVNF
E1 3 6 7 8 {GLFF}
R1 3 0 1E9
R2 3 0 1E9
R3 3 6 1E9
E2 6 4 5 0 10
R4 5 0 {RNVF}
R5 5 0 {RNVF}
R6 3 4 1E9
R7 4 0 1E9
G1 1 2 3 4 1E-6
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT VNSE_0  1 2
.PARAM FLW=10
.PARAM NLF=80
.PARAM NVR=35
.PARAM GLF={PWR(FLW,0.25)*NLF/1164}
.PARAM RNV={1.184*PWR(NVR,2)}
.MODEL DVN D KF={PWR(FLW,0.5)/1E11} IS=1.0E-16
I1 0 7 10E-3
I2 0 8 10E-3
D1 7 0 DVN
D2 8 0 DVN
E1 3 6 7 8 {GLF}
R1 3 0 1E9
R2 3 0 1E9
R3 3 6 1E9
E2 6 4 5 0 10
R4 5 0 {RNV}
R5 5 0 {RNV}
R6 3 4 1E9
R7 4 0 1E9
E3 1 2 3 4 1
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT VCCS_LIM_1_0  VC+ VC- IOUT+ IOUT-
.PARAM GAIN = 1E-4
.PARAM IPOS = .5
.PARAM INEG = -.5
G1 IOUT+ IOUT- VALUE={LIMIT(GAIN*V(VC+,VC-),INEG,IPOS)}
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT VCCS_LIMIT_IQ_0  VC+ VC- IOUT+ IOUT-
.PARAM GAIN = 1E-3
G1 IOUT- IOUT+ VALUE={IF( (V(VC+,VC-)<=0),0,GAIN*V(VC+,VC-) )}
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT CLAMP_AMP_LO_0  VC+ VC- VIN COM VO+ VO-
.PARAM G=1
GVO+ COM VO+ VALUE = {IF(V(VIN,COM)>V(VC+,COM),((V(VIN,COM)-V(VC+,COM))*G),0)}
GVO- COM VO- VALUE = {IF(V(VIN,COM)<V(VC-,COM),((V(VC-,COM)-V(VIN,COM))*G),0)}
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT CLAMP_AMP_HI_0  VC+ VC- VIN COM VO+ VO-
.PARAM G=10
GVO+ COM VO+ VALUE = {IF(V(VIN,COM)>V(VC+,COM),((V(VIN,COM)-V(VC+,COM))*G),0)}
GVO- COM VO- VALUE = {IF(V(VIN,COM)<V(VC-,COM),((V(VC-,COM)-V(VIN,COM))*G),0)}
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT VCCS_LIM_GR_0  VC+ VC- IOUT+ IOUT-
.PARAM GAIN = 1
.PARAM IPOS = 0.013
.PARAM INEG = -0.013
G1 IOUT+ IOUT- VALUE={LIMIT(GAIN*V(VC+,VC-),INEG,IPOS)}
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT VCCS_LIM_4_0  VC+ VC- IOUT+ IOUT-
.PARAM GAIN = 1
.PARAM IPOS = 1.04
.PARAM INEG = -1.04
G1 IOUT+ IOUT- VALUE={LIMIT(GAIN*V(VC+,VC-),INEG,IPOS)}
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT VCCS_LIM_CLAW+_0  VC+ VC- IOUT+ IOUT-
G1 IOUT+ IOUT- TABLE {ABS(V(VC+,VC-))} =
+(0, 1.17E-03)
+(0.0046251, 1.17E-3)
+(0.15716, 1.21E-3)
+(1.3309, 1.28E-3)
+(35.075, 2.12E-3)
+(35.680, 2.55E-3)
+(36.033, 2.84E-3)
+(37.416, 7.97E-3)
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT VCCS_LIM_CLAW-_0  VC+ VC- IOUT+ IOUT-
G1 IOUT+ IOUT- TABLE {ABS(V(VC+,VC-))} =
+(0.010, 2.50E-5)
+(0.070, 2.50E-5)
+(0.090, 5.80E-4)
+(0.100, 6.06E-4)
+(0.760, 7.14E-4) 
+(1.440, 7.62E-4)
+(8.000, 1.10E-3)
+(13.60, 1.55E-3)
+(15.45, 1.75E-3)
+(17.26, 2.15E-3)
+(18.87, 2.94E-3)
+(21.58, 4.50E-3)
+(25.53, 1.02E-2)
.ENDS
*



.SUBCKT VCCS_LIM_3_0  VC+ VC- IOUT+ IOUT-
.PARAM GAIN = 1
.PARAM IPOS = 0.435
.PARAM INEG = -0.435
G1 IOUT+ IOUT- VALUE={LIMIT(GAIN*V(VC+,VC-),INEG,IPOS)}
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT OL_SENSE_0  COM SW+ OLN  OLP
GSW+ COM SW+ VALUE = {IF((V(OLN,COM)>10E-3 | V(OLP,COM)>10E-3),1,0)}
.ENDS
*


.SUBCKT VCCS_EXT_LIM_0  VIN+ VIN- IOUT- IOUT+ VP+ VP-
.PARAM GAIN = 1
G1 IOUT+ IOUT- VALUE={LIMIT(GAIN*V(VIN+,VIN-),V(VP-,VIN-), V(VP+,VIN-))}
.ENDS
*
```

I also ensured that use the alternative node sequence of "3 2 4 11 1".  At least I think that is how this is supposed to work (you just align the PIN numbers with the sub-circuit parameter order?).

Finally, I enabled `pspice` compatibility mode by placing the following in my `.spiceiinit` file:

```
* user provided init file
set ngbehavior=ps
```

The simulation parameters were:

```
.tran 1u 1m
```

## Problem (Output)

My `Vout` is showing an output with a bias of 3.768V.  I expected the output to be 5*0.5 = 2.5V because the ratio of the feedback resistor and the input resistor was 5 and the `Vin` was set to oscillate around 0.5V.  Apparently, the `Vout` does not depend at all on `Vin` and is just this value all the time. Here is an image of the `Vout`.

Humm, it will not let me upload the image?  Very strange.  Anyway, it is oscillating around the stated 3.768.

The spice execution model output is the following:

```
Circuit: KiCad schematic
Reducing trtol to 1 for xspice 'A' devices
Doing analysis at TEMP = 27.000000 and TNOM = 27.000000
Warning: v2: no DC value, transient time 0 value used
Note: Starting dynamic gmin stepping
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-03 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-04 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-05 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-06 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-07 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   3.1623E-08 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   5.6234E-09 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   5.6234E-10 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   5.6234E-11 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   5.6234E-12 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-12 Note: One successful gmin step
Note: Dynamic gmin stepping completed
Initial Transient Solution
--------------------------
Node                                   Voltage
----                                   -------
vout                                    3.7681
net-_rf-pad2_                           1.0447
vin                                        0.5
xu1.esdn                           1.80025e-10
xu1.mid                                    2.5
xu1.37                                  1.0447
xu1.57                                   182.5
xu1.58                                  -177.5
xu1.51                                    42.5
xu1.52                                   -37.5
xu1.45                                 4.23694
xu1.vclp                               5.43694
xu1.56                                 4.23694
xu1.44                                 4.23694
xu1.43                                 6.63694
xu1.55                                 6.64173
xu1.42                                 6.64173
xu1.33                                  3.7681
xu1.79                                 2.5e-06
xu1.vee_b                              2.5e-06
xu1.80                                     3.5
xu1.vcc_b                                    5
vcc2                                         5
vee                                          0
xu1.86                                  1.0465
xu1.22                                  2.4998
xu1.23                               0.0177525
xu1.26                                 1.04665
xu1.xu3.e1_int1                       -1.45334
xu1.24                                 1.04665
xu1.27                             1.80025e-10
xu1.xu3.e2_int1                           -2.5
xu1.25                             1.80025e-10
xu1.xu1.vref                              2.46
xu1.xu1.vshf                           3.08468
xu1.vimon                              3.04468
xu1.xu1.zc                                 3.5
xu1.xu1.gzc_int1                             1
xu1.crs                                    3.5
xu1.xu1.gcr_int1                             1
xu1.28                                 152.684
xu1.29                                 37.4238
xu1.30                                 152.657
xu1.31                                 2.53753
xu1.32                                 152.619
xu1.xu2.g1_int1                         150.12
xu1.cl_clamp                           5.43694
xu1.34                                 6.65013
xu1.35                                 6.65013
xu1.clamp                              6.65013
xu1.xu5.g1_int1                         0.0048
xu1.36                                 107.165
xu1.38                                 2.50479
xu1.39                                 2.50479
xu1.40                                     2.5
xu1.41                                     2.5
xu1.xi_nn.7                           0.833786
xu1.xi_nn.8                           0.833786
xu1.xi_nn.3                                  0
xu1.xi_nn.6                                  0
xu1.xi_nn.4                                  0
xu1.xi_nn.5                                  0
xu1.xi_np.7                           0.833786
xu1.xi_np.8                           0.833786
xu1.xi_np.3                                  0
xu1.xi_np.6                                  0
xu1.xi_np.4                                  0
xu1.xi_np.5                                  0
xu1.xe_n.7                            0.833786
xu1.xe_n.8                            0.833786
xu1.xe_n.3                                   0
xu1.xe_n.6                                   0
xu1.xe_n.4                                   0
xu1.xe_n.5                                   0
xu1.esdp                                1.0447
xu1.vsense                             6.65013
xu1.xvccs_lim_1.g1_int1            0.000104665
xu1.46                                 1.04665
xu1.47                                     2.5
xu1.48                                    2.75
xu1.49                                 2.49995
xu1.50                                 1.50283
xu1.xiqpos.g1_int1                  0.00054468
xu1.xiqneg.g1_int1                           0
xu1.53                                     2.5
xu1.xcl_amp.gvo+_int1                        0
xu1.54                                     2.5
xu1.xcl_amp.gvo-_int1                        0
xu1.60                                     2.5
xu1.xgr_amp.gvo+_int1                        0
xu1.59                                 6.65013
xu1.61                                     2.5
xu1.xgr_amp.gvo-_int1                        0
xu1.62                                     2.5
xu1.63                                     2.5
xu1.xgr_src.g1_int1                          0
xu1.64                                     2.5
xu1.65                                     2.5
xu1.xcl_src.g1_int1                          0
xu1.66                                 3.76689
xu1.xclawp.g1_int1                  0.00123311
xu1.67                                0.678768
xu1.xclawn.g1_int1                 0.000678766
xu1.68                                 3.76689
xu1.69                                0.678768
xu1.vcc_clp                            3.76689
xu1.vee_clp                           0.678768
xu1.70                                 2.50121
xu1.xclaw_amp.gvo+_int1             0.00121319
xu1.vout_s                              3.7681
xu1.71                                     2.5
xu1.xclaw_amp.gvo-_int1                      0
xu1.72                                 2.50121
xu1.73                                     2.5
xu1.claw_clamp                         5.43694
xu1.xclaw_src.g1_int1               0.00121319
xu1.sw_ol                                  2.5
xu1.74                                     2.5
xu1.xol_sense.gsw+_int1                      0
xu1.75                                 3.04468
xu1.76                                  3.7681
xu1.77                                 5.43694
xu1.78                                 1.04665
xu1.xvcm_clamp.g1_int1                -1.45334
xu1.81                                     2.5
xu1.82                              2.5025e-06
xu1.83                                       5
xu1.84                                 1.04645
xu1.85                                 1.04645
b.xu1.xvcm_clamp.bg1#branch                  0
b.xu1.xol_sense.bgsw+#branch                 0
b.xu1.xclaw_src.bg1#branch                   0
b.xu1.xclaw_amp.bgvo-#branch                 0
b.xu1.xclaw_amp.bgvo+#branch                 0
b.xu1.xclawn.bg1#branch                      0
b.xu1.xclawp.bg1#branch                      0
b.xu1.xcl_src.bg1#branch                     0
b.xu1.xgr_src.bg1#branch                     0
b.xu1.xgr_amp.bgvo-#branch                   0
b.xu1.xgr_amp.bgvo+#branch                   0
b.xu1.xcl_amp.bgvo-#branch                   0
b.xu1.xcl_amp.bgvo+#branch                   0
b.xu1.xiqneg.bg1#branch                      0
b.xu1.xiqpos.bg1#branch                      0
b.xu1.xvccs_lim_1.bg1#branch                 0
b.xu1.xu5.bg1#branch                         0
b.xu1.xu2.bg1#branch                         0
b.xu1.xu1.bgcr#branch                        0
b.xu1.xu1.bgzc#branch                        0
b.xu1.xu3.be2#branch                         0
b.xu1.xu3.be1#branch                         0
h.xu1.h1#branch                    -5.4468e-13
v.xu1.v4#branch                     0.00054468
h.xu1.h3#branch                              0
v.xu1.v12#branch                    0.00479585
h.xu1.h2#branch                              0
v.xu1.v11#branch                             0
e.xu1.e1#branch                   -3.80027e-08
e.xu1.e4#branch                              0
e.xu1.e5#branch                   -1.26811e-12
e.xu1.xe_n.e3#branch              -1.99999e-08
e.xu1.xe_n.e2#branch                         0
e.xu1.xe_n.e1#branch                         0
e.xu1.xi_np.e2#branch                        0
e.xu1.xi_np.e1#branch                        0
e.xu1.xi_nn.e2#branch                        0
e.xu1.xi_nn.e1#branch                        0
e.xu1.xu1.eshf#branch                        0
e.xu1.xu3.e2#branch                          0
e.xu1.xu3.e1#branch                          0
v2#branch                            0.0005447
v3#branch                          -0.00071968
v4#branch                            -0.000175
v.xu1.xu1.v1#branch                          0
v.xu1.v_os#branch                  -7.9498e-14
v.xu1.vcm_max#branch              -9.99999e-13
v.xu1.vcm_min#branch                   2.5e-12
v.xu1.v_orp#branch                           0
v.xu1.v_orn#branch                           0
v.xu1.v_iscn#branch                      4e-11
v.xu1.v_iscp#branch                     -4e-11
v.xu1.v_grn#branch                     1.8e-10
v.xu1.v_grp#branch                    -1.8e-10
 Reference value :  0.00000e+00

No. of Data Rows : 1008
```

Can somebody help me understand why I am not seeing what I expected to see (an oscillation around 2.5V for `Vout`)?

## EDIT:

I have taken the suggestions that have been provided and swapped the op-amp inputs.  The schematic is now:

[image]

However, when I run the simulation, the graphical output of `Vout` is:

[image]

This is still not he magnitude of 2.5V which is what I was expecting.  The simulation output is the following:

```
Circuit: KiCad schematic
Reducing trtol to 1 for xspice 'A' devices
Doing analysis at TEMP = 27.000000 and TNOM = 27.000000
Warning: v2: no DC value, transient time 0 value used
Note: Starting dynamic gmin stepping
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-03 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-04 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-05 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-06 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-07 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-08 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-09 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-10 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-11 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-12 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-12 Note: One successful gmin step
Note: Dynamic gmin stepping completed
Initial Transient Solution
--------------------------
Node                                   Voltage
----                                   -------
vout                                 0.0700215
net-_rf-pad2_                         0.428352
vin                                        0.5
xu1.esdn                              0.428352
xu1.mid                                    2.5

... Truncated because of post length requirements

 Reference value :  0.00000e+00

No. of Data Rows : 1014
```

Any further suggestions, remember, I am very new to this, so I could be missing something very basic.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: check the opamp input connections! You built a comparator with LOTS of hysteresis, not an amplifier!

Comment: A simple answer for a very well written question. You get my +1!

Comment: A couple of things; as the amplifier is inverting and it looks like you have a 0,.5V offset, it would swing around *-2.5V*. The negative supply is 0 so you cannot get the amplifier into the linear region. Try adding a -5V supply for V-

Comment: Why does V4 = 0 volts?

Comment: I was doing that by setting V4 to -5V, but then the simulation fails to run with the error: doAnalyses: Too many iterations without convergence
run simulation(s) aborted

Comment: I thought that the LM324 created its own differential input and the V+ line got the magnitude of the differential voltage, while pin 11 went to ground.  That is what the NTE987 was supposed to be configured as, I thought?  Am I wrong here?

Comment: Wait, got it.  I needed to setup V4 as +5V because of the way I had it configured.  So, am I mis-reading the NTE987 and it too should be getting a + and - bias voltage across pins 4 and 11?

Comment: Why do the voltage arrows at the sources point upwards? In my opinion, it should be pointing down. Maybe you measure the voltage VCC2 and Vee in your graph.

Comment: @TomKuschel That's a difference in notation between Europe and North America. A particularly frustrating one, if you ask me.

Comment: @Hearth ok, I see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have swapped the inverting and non inverting inputs of your op amp.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have updated the answer to include a follow-on situation.  Unfortunately, I am still not seeing what I expected. The output is now showing a gain of 0.14 (0.07/0.5) vice the gain of -5 that I was expecting.  I had to truncate some of the simulation output to fit inside the 30000 character limit.  (How do people ge around that?  Can I remove some of the original post?)

Comment: @JustaceClutter If it didn't help, why did you mark the question as solved?

Comment: @pipe It did.  I did finally get the 2.5V that I was expecting.  I had a slightly related question in my comments above on how to interpret the NTE987.  I also flagged this answer as correct.